I am trying to use mat-chip-row, mat-chip-grid and they don't seem to be recognized even if I imported the module MatChipsModule
I am using these Angular versions
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.6.1",
    "jest-editor-support": "*",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }

what can I do about it? I don't want to change the angular version because it's possible to mess up the whole project.
I added this import{ MatChipInputEvent, MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';  and also added the MatChipsModule to imports in .module.ts but the elements mat-chip-row, mat-chip-grid I used in .html were still not recognized.
